# vb.net Reference Assembly WithEvents not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly, activexobject

I have been searching this for forever and have not been able to find an answer so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am originally using this dll as an activeX control through .asp pages and it works perfectly.  I am now having to rewrite it as a class because my boss asked me too.  So in my project I have right clicked and added reference name.dll.  The FileType of this is Assembly.

so i created a variable

`Friend WithEvents scan As name.Integration.ActiveX.ActiveXObject`

With this I am able to call its methods and it works perfectly at this point.  However, after I call a method it runs a process and starts waiting for a card to be inserted into the scanner.  When a card is inserted into the scanner it is suppose to throw an event and then start scanning.

Once I insert a card it scans but the issue I'm having is my program is not catching any of the 50 events it is throwing.  Does anyone know how or why?  I'm desperately needing to fix this.

Comment: Is a function using a "handles scan.<event>"?

Comment: This almost always requires a message loop.  The kind you get from a Winforms or WPF application.  Application.Run() required.

Comment: I've never used WPF but I do know that there is a function I call that starts the software.  it's called Initialize.  Once I do that the software starts listening and firing events as necessary.

Comment: @SpectralGhost it is using a handles scan.Event.  Sorry I didn't see your comment when I originally responded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (and I'm reading between the lines here) you have an ActiveX control from a third party. Your previous web page used this control. You now instead reference the dll that contains the ActiveX control, so VS automatically creates a .net wrapper around the ActiveX component. Is that correct?

If yes, confirm you are referencing the correct type from the correct libary.

1. Use the Object Browser to view the dll's types. I think you'll find you have two libraries associated with the dll. For example, assume your library is named "ThirdParty". You may see "AxThirdParty" as well as "Interop.ThirdParty". The "interop" library contains most classes. However, the "Ax..." library is key to handling events. Your object that declares events from be from this library. If you don't see this libary, you may need to add the control to a Windows .net form to get VS to create it for you.
2. Don't try to handle events in the "Ax..." library that are hidden. Note that handling hidden events does not cause compile errors, but nor do they ever get raised. Do you see the event your trying to handle in the "Ax..." library? If so, is it shown in light gray? Note that VS will rename any interop event that conflicts with standard control events. For example, the ActiveX control's click event gets named "ClickEvent" and it is the ClickEvent event you want to handle, not the Click event.

Note that above applies to Windows forms. I think Hans is right about the message loop.

Comment: Yes the ActiveX file is 3rd party.  Now does it matter if the filetype says that it is an assembly file?

Also an interop version doesn't exists.  The only file that exists is name.integration.ActiveX.  That is the only file I have to download.  Should I possibly use a Windows form and drag the activeX file on there or is it because those are hidden, they will never call my Event Handlers?

Comment: This is weird, when I do the whole WithEvents I get the event OnSchemeComplete.  But when i search through it in .net Reflector, it is called schemeComplete.  Should I see if I can find out how to catch SchemeComplete?

Comment: Of course I'm not familiar with the control you have. Typically I'd expect something named "OnSchemeComplete" to be an overridable method of a base class, not an event. It might help if you could provide the related code...

Comment: Also, more info about the ActiveX please. Did you add it to your project from the .NET or COM tab of the references dialog? If the COM tab, you might want to confirm with your vendor that their stuff will work with .net.

Comment: well the code i can't write because I don't have access to the event so I haven't written any yet.  The event was created by me selecting, in the top left drop down, selecting my variable created with the WithEvents, and then on the top right drop down I am selecting one of it's 50 events which is OnSchemeComplete.  and .net explorer (which allows me to look at the dll) shows it as an event.

and neither.  I just referenced it since it isn't a window form app.  BUT that being said, I can find it under the .net framework components

Comment: Sorry if i'm not being very helpful here.  Never been the greatest with describing what I am really thinking.